# Using the jQuery each function to count divs with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, magento

I created a css class for 8 divs, I need to use the each function of jquery to count the divs and show the result in the page's html, example: "8 divs appear".

I created a code but it doesn't work, it doesn't show the result.

code:

```
 <script>
    $( ".class" ).each(function( index ) {
      console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you post your console log output. It can't be done here. So u help us out on that part. Your html might be helpful too.

Comment: Here the image of the console log output.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JM8zP.png

Answer (score 2):

if you just want to count them, you can do:
`$('.class').length`

Comment: I created a specific class just for these divs, I want my code to count by the css class, I'm locked. :(

Comment: `$('.class').length + ' divs appear'`

Answer (score 0):

From `each()` method to get whole same class divs `index` + `content` or You want to count how many divs has same class then simply use `.length`.

*Note: Check on **`Full page.`*** then you can see same class divs `count result`.

```js
// Console inded with each div text.
$('.sameclass').each(function(index){
  console.log(index +':'+ $(this).text());
});

//Count How many divs has (sameclass) class. 
$('.result').text($('.sameclass').length);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="sameclass">Text #1</div>
<div class="sameclass">Text #2</div>
<div class="sameclass">Text #3</div>
<div class="sameclass">Text #4</div>
<div class="sameclass">Text #5</div>
<div class="sameclass">Text #6</div>
<div class="sameclass">Text #7</div>
<div class="sameclass">Text #8</div>
<hr>
<p>Total divs has (sameclass): <strong class="result"></strong></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

After a few attempts, I managed to solve the problem.

I created three codes and they worked and gave me the result I wanted. Thanks a lot for the help.

1.

```
    var totalPageProducts;
jQuery('.products-grid .item').each(function(index, value) {
totalPageProducts = index + 1;
jQuery('.show-no').html('Showing '+ totalPageProducts +' products');
});
```

2.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery('.show-no').html('Showing '+ jQuery('.products-grid .item').length +' products');
});
```

3.

```
jQuery('.show-no').html('Showing '+ jQuery('.products-grid .item').length +' products');
```